# JS Call function inside function run-time with string

Tags: javascript, function, runtime

I've found [here is a good explication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) of the difference between run-time functions and parse-time ones.
Bit what i'm trying to do is something like this

```
var funtionName = 'functionInside';
var start = function(){
    var a = function(){doSomething();}
    return {functionInside:a} 
};
```

And i want to call function 'functionInside' with the variable, something like

```
start.window[funtionName]()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do that depending on what you need.

Here are two examples:

```
var start = {
  functionInside : function(){
    doSomething();    
  }
};

start[funtionName](); //different ways to invoke
start.functionInside();
```

Here's another approach:

```
var start = function() {
  this.functionInside = function() {doSomething();}
}

var s = new start();

s[funtionName](); //different ways to invoke
s.functionInside();
```

Comment: and if i want to know which function was call??

Comment: add conole.log or alerts in different areas so you can see.  Or in chrome, add stops so you can trace the code.